# GPS location jumping around

Tags: android, gps, location

Hi I wonder why my location on google map (using phone's GPS)keeps jumping around when I stand still [see included image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTEaM.png)

I'm not shore if it is problem of the GPS module accurancy or if I'm missing something in my code cause in criteria I'm using

```
criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
criteria.setSpeedAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
```

also I've tried to change frequency of location manager updates

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 500, 0, this);
```

and as last thing I'm calculating distance from old coordinates to new when location changes and when it is more than 1m  than I draw line on the map. I didn't include minimal distance when I' making the request on location manager updatesbecause I want to display location but no to draw the line, when location changes less than 1m. So am I missing something or is this the fault of GPS sensor ?

Comment: Does it only happen when you turn the gps on?

Comment: You could try running it on an emulator, and sending just one location.  That will definitely not change, and so if everything works fine there you can conclude the device is probably giving lots of different location updates.  You may want to decrease your sensitivity, like maybe 10 meters, but then I don't know what your app does.

Comment: Well that's the problem I'm facing. The app will be used for GPS drawing games. So I wonder when I change condition to draw only when the distance between two points will be 10m or more if I'm not going to loose prescition like in city on corners etc.

Comment: I have got the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991613/locationmanager-and-jumping-coordinates Any working solution, bro?

Comment: Well only way I've solved it was with tweaking the settings. I've programmed a check in onlocationchanged() and checked if the distance between locations is more than 2 meters (there is a method for it). For this I've created location object that kept old coordinates and only rewritten them if the drawing was on and if the distance was grather than 2 meters. While I've worked with this I haven't found any other soloutions but found it is due to inaccurancy of the GPS modules and due to atmospheric conditions. You just have to tweak the refresh and drawing settings.