# LocationManager and jumping coordinates

Tags: java, android, google-maps, locationmanager

Take a look at this image. You see that some how LocationManager  gives weird coordinates. It looks like they jump. But at the same time native google map app display correct location of the moving  device.

I tested app with 3 different smartphones under Android 7.0.0 and 7.1.1 and get the same result more or less.

Please help me check my code to see which settings it is missing still.

Thank you!

[image]

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;

public class gps_service2 extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "GPS SERVICE";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 15000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;
    Context context;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
    {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);

            try
            {
                ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(context, "App_Settings", 0);
                AppSettings appSettings = complexPreferences.getObject("App_Settings", AppSettings.class);

                boolean isMobileDataEnabled = Utils.isMobileDataEnabled(context);

                if (appSettings != null && (isMobileDataEnabled)) {

                    LocationItem locationItem = new LocationItem();
                    locationItem.DeviceID = appSettings.getDeviceID();
                    locationItem.Latitude =  Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                    locationItem.Longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                    Date d = new Date();
                    CharSequence timeOfRequest = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", d.getTime());  
                    locationItem.TimeOfRequest = timeOfRequest.toString();
                    locationItem.SerialNumber = appSettings.getSerialNumber();

                    mLastLocation.set(location);

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String requestObject = gson.toJson(locationItem);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Формирование URL API сервера");
                    String url = appSettings.getIpAddress() + "/api/staff/savedata";
                    makeRequest(url, requestObject, dLocation);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Ошибка: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        context = this;
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }

    public void makeRequest(String uri, String json, DLocation dLocation) {
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("URLConnection");
        handlerThread.start();
        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        Runnable myRunnable = createRunnable(uri, json, dLocation);
        mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }

    private Runnable createRunnable(final String uri, final String data,final DLocation dLocation){

        Runnable aRunnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {   
                    //Connect
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(12000);
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000); 

                    urlConnection.connect();

                    //Write
                    OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    try {
                        writer.write(data);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG,"Ошибка записи в буфер для пережачи по HTTP");
                    }
                    writer.close();
                    outputStream.close();

                    //Read
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                    String line = null;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }

                    bufferedReader.close();
                    String result = sb.toString();

                    Log.d(TAG, result);                    

                }
                catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Ошибка HTTP " + e.getMessage());
                }
                catch( Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        return aRunnable;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty typical behavior from a smartphone/consumer-grade GPS. To reduce the fluctuations you'll need to normalize the results. One approach is to compute the geographic center from a queue of coordinates, for example: https://github.com/Esri/cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation/blob/master/src/com/esri/cordova/geolocation/utils/GeodataHelper.java#L56

```
public class Coordinate {
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
    public float accuracy;
}

public static Coordinate getGeographicCenter(final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Coordinate> queue){
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double z = 0;
    float accuracy = 0;
    int radiusKM = 6367;

    for(final Coordinate coordinate : queue){
        accuracy += coordinate.accuracy;

        // Convert latitude and longitude to radians
        final double latRad = Math.PI * coordinate.latitude / 180;
        final double lonRad = Math.PI * coordinate.longitude / 180;

        // Convert to cartesian coords
        x += radiusKM * Math.cos(latRad) * Math.cos(lonRad);
        y += radiusKM * Math.cos(latRad) * Math.sin(lonRad);
        z += radiusKM * Math.sin(latRad);
    }

    // Get our averages
    final double xAvg = x / queue.size();
    final double yAvg = y / queue.size();
    final double zAvg = z / queue.size();
    final float accuracyAvg = accuracy / queue.size();

    // Convert cartesian back to radians
    final double sphericalLatRads = Math.asin(zAvg / radiusKM);
    final double sphericalLonRads = Math.atan2(yAvg, xAvg);

    // Convert radians back to latitude and longitude
    Coordinate centerPoint = new Coordinate();
    centerPoint.latitude = sphericalLatRads * (180 / Math.PI);
    centerPoint.longitude = sphericalLonRads * (180 / Math.PI);
    centerPoint.accuracy = accuracyAvg;

    return centerPoint;
}
```

Comment: Please add some code snippets to indicate how to "normalize the results". Links may be broken in the future.

Comment: Hi! Andy! Thank you so much to you comments! Would you mind to advice hou much coordinates and how offen we have to use for the suggested function, please? Let's say we get 6 points per minute and calculate the best location each minute is it ok?

Comment: An active GPS will typically send out way more than 6 updates per minute, even when the device is not moving. Try starting out with 10 coordinates and experiment to get your desired results. Smaller queue size is better for application performance. I also suggest using Android Studio tools to keep an eye on CPU, memory usage and garbage collection when you do your testing. Intensive GPS usage plus normalization routines using the current generation of chipsets can be very hard on battery life and user experience.

Comment: I've tried this and sometime it take me off the road even when I'm on the road. So for me it just decreases the accuracy but fix jumping problem a little as my app still jumps but less. Any approach to minimize those random location jumps.

Comment: @AshutoshSagar what you are seeing is the inherent inaccuracy of the current generation of consumer phone GPS. The only way to completely eliminate jumping is to combine averaging with logic that "snaps" your position to the nearest map feature like a section of road or intersection. That's advanced mapping capabilities and not all APIs support it.

Comment: @Andy G that's the only way I think left is to handle them logically.

Comment: Thanks @Andy G about your answer. I used this answer for my navigation app.On cycle of normalize, List of queue has three location. but result hasn't good LatLng by high accuracy. what is the reason?